# How to update python array after certain operation

Tags: python, numpy

In the following code, I have an array named `List`. When for loop runs the first time I slice some values of this array and make a new array named `new`. Now I want to replace `List` by `new` so that when for loop runs the second time it slices values from `new` not from `List`. So how can I do that?

```
def update():
    low =[1.5, 2.5, 3.0]
    high = [4.0, 4.5, 5.0]
    for i in range(len(low)):
        h1 = low[i]
        h2 = high[i]
        List=np.arange(1.0, 5.01, 0.5)
        hList =[]
        for k in range(len(List)):
            hList.append(round(List[k],2))

        low_ind =hList.index(low[i])
        high_ind = hList.index(high[i])
        #Slicing
        List = List[low_ind:high_ind]``
```

Here is result

```
`i is:  0
List:  [1.  1.5 2.  2.5 3.  3.5 4.  4.5 5. ]
After_Slicing
[1.5 2.  2.5 3.  3.5]

i is:  1
List:  [1.  1.5 2.  2.5 3.  3.5 4.  4.5 5. ]
After_Slicing
[2.5 3.  3.5 4. ]

i is:  2
List:  [1.  1.5 2.  2.5 3.  3.5 4.  4.5 5. ]
After_Slicing
[3.  3.5 4.  4.5]`
```

Comment: `List = new`?...

Comment: No it doesn't update

Comment: Why do you need `new` to begin with? just write `List = List[low_ind:high_ind]`

Comment: Naming an array "List" is a bit confusing, but I guess it's not as bad as the more common practice of naming a list "array". ;)

Comment: @herry Yes it does, or show us wrong with a [mcve]

Comment: To start with your function doesn't return `List` anyway...which is redefined within the for loop as well!

Comment: The point of this loop is what exactly?

Comment: When i=0 then after slicing I get [1.5, 2, 2.5,3,3.5]. But when i=1 and I print List is is same as before. It should be [1.5, 2, 2.5,3,3.5].

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure of what you want to do, but adding this line:

```
        #Slicing
        new = List[low_ind:high_ind]
        List = new #This line
```

seems to update the List.

Comment: I also updated in this way but I am not getting required result

Comment: What is the required result?

Comment: When i=0 then after slicing I get [1.5, 2, 2.5,3,3.5]. But when i=1 and I print List is is same as before. It should be [1.5, 2, 2.5,3,3.5]

Comment: You are redeclaring List for every run: List=np.arange(1.0, 5.01, 0.5).

Simply put that outside the for loop and you should be fine.

Comment: No i have updated my post and showed result that I am getting. I am talking about i in  for loop

Comment: Yes, but when you call write: `List=np.arange(1.0, 5.01, 0.5)` it will always be the same since you are setting it back to default. If you do this outside of the for loop, you will not have it becoming the same over and over again. But, you will get another error.